# HTML audio src for absolute URL does not work in React Component

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-audio, use-state

I have a simple music web app that changes the music and image cover onClick, the problem is when I click on a song, the cover image change correctly but the audio source does not play (the src attribute set correctly but it is not playable)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState({});
  const server_url = `http://localhost:8765`;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(server_url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsonRes => {
      
      setPlaying(jsonRes.songs[0]);
      setSongs(jsonRes.songs);
    });
    
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <img src={`${server_url}/music/imgs/${playing.img}`} width="200" height="200" />
        <audio controls>
          <source src={`${server_url}/music/mp3/${playing.mp3}`} type="audio/mpeg" />
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
        {
        songs.map(song => {
          return (
            <li key={song.id} onClick={() => setPlaying(song)}>{song.name}</li>
          )
        })
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The response from the localhost:8765 is like this:

```
   {"songs":
      [
{"id":1,"name":"Hello","singer":"Adele","img":"adele.png","type":"pop","mp3":"Adele.mp3"},
{"id":2,"name":"de una vez","singer":"Selena gomez","img":"selena.png","type":"pop","mp3":"Selena.mp3"},
{"id":3,"name":"Bayda","singer":"Navid","img":"navid.png","type":"pop","mp3":"Navid.mp3"},
{"id":4,"name":"Takin' Back My Love ","singer":"Enrique Iglesias","img":"enrique.png","type":"Pop","mp3":"Enrique.mp3"}
]
}
```

Comment: Is this a typo? Should it be:

    `${server_url}/music/mp3/${playing}.mp3`

Comment: Actually, I don't think so, because it is the index of song object and the value itself has .mp3 
I updated the question to show the response from the server

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: On setPlaying, please verify the song is downloading in the Network tab. Ensure the path loads with a HTTP status code of 200.

Use the autoplay HTML attribute on the audio JSX element (ie <audio controls  autoplay>)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it does not work. I checked the network tap and there is different behaviour between image and media, in the image tab first time the page loaded it to search for an undefined image and then it corrects it by searching the image name from server. But in the media tab, it only searches for undefined and not for current media, however, the src attribute for audio stated correctly and if I open the src in the new tab the music play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your React container component will initially render with a broken image and audio player. The audio player doesn't recover so the second audio `source` element doesn't load correctly

1. When the fetch data call takes time, you should prevent the undefined song from rendering or set a default song to play. **Detailed answer**: Add a new second `return` statement after the `useEffect`. When `songs` is an empty array (which you set as default on line 4) then `return` a spinner or `return` null (React will not render the component, it's basically skipped). OR secondary solution is to set better defaults on line 4 to be an image and song that has a valid path so it will load before the long running fetch data call.
2. In the existing render, set the song to automatically play so the user doesn't need to press play. **Detailed answer**:  Use the autoplay HTML attribute on the audio JSX element (ie `<audio controls autoplay>`)
3. Add defensive code for your fetch data call. Add a `try` / `catch` inside your `useEffect` so server errors are caught and handled. To prevent your component from crashing

Comment: Thanks, It seems it is going to work but I still have some problems. I set one of the songs as the default song in useState for playing and also add autoPlay attribute in audio tag, by doing these changes, when the page load for the first time, the songs downloaded successfully but other songs are not playing when I click them. https://github.com/samanehvj/music-app-server
https://github.com/samanehvj/music-app-ui
these are my repository for this project